# $_SESSION variables don't seem to be working when visiting a site from a masked, redirected URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication, session-variables, redirect

I'm redirecting a URL from the registrar. I have a login form on the page it is redirecting to using $_SESSION variables to store the username and password—which work great when visiting the site directly, or even from a subdomain. (test.com/new or new.test.com).

When I visit the site from "this.com", which redirects to "new.test.com", the login form seems to allow entry (I get no error that the credentials weren't passed correctly), but then nothing loads on the next page—similar to what happens when a php file is accessed in browser on a server.

If I log in to the normal site successfully (test.com/new), then open a new window and navigate to it using the redirected URL, it requires log in again, but when I do, it allows me in to the site. The page only shows up blank when I try to open it without logging in first from the normal URL.

Is there something I can set differently to allow this to work?

Comment: Session data depends on cookies. If you set your cookie to be valid only in particular dir it will not be seen in another. You also cannot set cookie on one domain and use on another.

Comment: The URL is being redirected to the same directory. The username and password are being set when visiting from the redirected URL. The variable would be stored under the URL that is being entered, right? If it is redirecting, how could the variable be stored under another domain?

Comment: It makes sense to me that it doesn't work now that I understand masked URL forwarding better. I believe it didn't work because masked forwarding from the registrar is rendered in a frame.